# How can I tell why my query is taking so long?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is taking a lot longer then usual, and I cannot tell if it is stuck.

The query is something like this:

```
INSERT XXXXXX WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT * FROM YYYYYY with (NOLOCK)
WHERE ZZZZZZZZ = 1
```

This will insert hundreds of millions of rows.  I have an index on ZZZZZZZZ.

There are no blocking sessions.  When I check sys.dm_exec_requests, it shows that the last wait type is **PAGEIOLATCH_SH**  I'm not sure what this means, except that it has something to do with I/O.

sys.dm_exec_sessions shows the status is RUNNING, but sp_who2 shows it as SUSPENDED.

I tried to see if the table is growing, but when I call sp_spaceused XXXXXX, I keep getting the same values.

What else can I do?

**UPDATE:**

With the help of the answers below, I have found that there is [an I/O issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687568/how-can-i-tell-if-a-long-running-query-is-stuck/3687620#3687620), and that my query [is resulting in an average of about 600 records being inserted per minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687568/how-can-i-tell-if-a-long-running-query-is-stuck/3687764#3687764)).

**What is my next step?**

What can I do before I start to assume that my disk is going bad?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but as a work-around, on SQL 2008 at least, you can use `INSERT XXXXX WITH (TABLOCK)` to minimize logging and reduce IO.

Comment: Does the row count value of the table X property sheet show changes?

Comment: no.  There has been no changed in the last few hours.

Comment: 600 records per minute? Is there anything in the event log about disc problems?

Comment: Nothing in the event log that stands out.  none of the very small number of warnings/errors were disk related.

Comment: Any other applications, concurrent activity that could be affecting things?

Comment: not a thing is running besides SQL Server.  The machine has 8 processors and 48GB of memory (all of it is allocated to SQL server).

Comment: You might be better off asking this over at server fault. Are source and target both on the same disc? What about transaction logs? If they are on different discs maybe use perfmon to see if one disc has obviously higher queue length values.

Comment: I asked over there already.  The level of response was far lower there than here.  As for your questions, tempdb is on the C drive (1.5TB available) and the database files (MDF and LDF are on the other drive (1.6TB available).  Perfmon didn't show me anything interesting there.

Comment: @Gabriel - Did this query finish yet?

Comment: No. The speed seemed to go up when another query was also running, but when that one finished, this one went down to about 160 records/min.  I finally just killed it.  I need to figure it out!  This is supposed to be running once a day, but has been taking more than 3 days to run before I kill it every time.

Comment: Maybe have a look through the [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) document linked to from here so you can get an idea of what additional monitoring you need to do and how to analyse the results. Also maybe check out [SQLNexus on CodePlex](http://sqlnexus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look over these this weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try the following

```
select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
```

does the resource address it's waiting on change at all?

```
select * 
into #t1
from sys.dm_os_wait_stats

waitfor delay '00:01'

select * 
into #t2
from sys.dm_os_wait_stats

SELECT #t2.wait_type, 
#t2.waiting_tasks_count - #t1.waiting_tasks_count as waiting_tasks_count, 
#t2.wait_time_ms- #t1.wait_time_ms as wait_time_ms, 
#t2.signal_wait_time_ms- #t1.signal_wait_time_ms as signal_wait_time_ms
FROM #t2  JOIN #t1 ON #t2.wait_type = #t1.wait_type
where #t2.wait_type not in ('CHECKPOINT_QUEUE','CHKPT','FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT',
'KSOURCE_WAKEUP',
'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP',
'LOGMGR_QUEUE',
'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH',
'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH' ,
'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT',
'XE_TIMER_EVENT', 'WAITFOR')
order by wait_time_ms desc
```

Comment: It does seem to be changing periodically.

Comment: @Gabriel - If you check the values in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` and then again a minute later what is taking the time? Is it all `PAGEIOLATCH`?

Comment: If I execute select * from sys.dm_os_wait_stats, there are 485 records.  I'm not sure what to look at.

Comment: The top wait type is PAGEIOLATCH_SH (waiting_tasks_count = 3684, wait_time_ms = 94040, signal_wait_time_ms = 0).  The others with any values are:  SLEEP_TASK, BROKER_TO_FLUSH, and SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD (small values in SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD)

Comment: @Gabriel - Nothing new. Just confirms that it is an I/O issue.

Comment: @Martin: What can I do (now that I know its an I/O issue)?

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts that might help with the insert:

Are there any insert triggers on `xxxxxx`? Those could have a significant impact on a large insert operation.

Are there non-clustered indexes on `xxxxxx` that could be disabled during the load? That would also go a long way towards helping.

```
/* Before */
alter index YourIndex on xxxxxx disable
/* After */
alter index YourIndex on xxxxxx rebuild
```

Comment: There are no triggers on xxxxxxx.  There is an index on xxxxx, but I am already doing what you suggest (disable, run, enable).

Comment: @Gabriel, for minimal logging on the insert, you need either a) a heap, or b) an **empty** clustered index. any other configuration will produce full logging.

Comment: @Gabriel, seems you can get minimal logging w/ a non-empty clustered index, so long as the rows are ordered by the clustering key and you enable a trace flag. See here for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/23/minimal-logging-changes-in-sql-server-2008-part-2.aspx

Comment: more gory details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx. Also, the other biggie is that you can't be in full recovery model.

Answer (score 1):

Is the insert inside of a transaction? If it is, you could try to check the transaction details inside Sys.Dm_tran_database_Transactions. It shows the current number of entries writen to the transaction log along with some other health stats that should be changing over time:

SELECT * FROM Sys.Dm_tran_Database_Transactions

This is a link to the MSDN artical that explains the columns: [MSDN Column documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186957.aspx)

Hope that helps

Comment: It does show that there is a transaction on that particular database.  It seems to be that of this query (although I didn't begin any transactions).  the number of rows are growing slowly.

Comment: Sql by default will wrap everything in its own transaction implicitly if you didn't specify one explicitly and autocommit if it didn't error out

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sounds like you may be in a DW-style environment, moving lots of data from one table to another. Assuming you are on SQL Server 2008, see this whitepaper:

[The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(SQL.100).aspx)

See the sections on **minimal logging**, and further down on **partition switching**.

It helps to read the whole paper through a few times, so you really grok what's going on beneath the covers, and why certain combinations of data + indexing work and others don't.

Partition switching makes minimal logging easy to achieve, since it gives you an empty target table, and allows new data to come on-line in an instant, once the load has finished. Might need enterprise edition, though.

Answer (score 0):

DW Fact table?

http://books.google.com/books?id=eBacaL61sa4C&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=remove+index+when+updating+fact+table&source=bl&ots=MFB8HnmYRl&sig=w680N0GA3oSiJaS1mU_Z_WzW1VY&hl=en&ei=-EeOTKaQDtPyOeqZtLsK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false

p268

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer or a question... I read the passage from that book. What does it have to do with this?

Comment: If your table is in a DW, then it's a possible answer. i.e. remove the indexes during the update. If not, then it isn't :)